# Force yarn install instead of npm install for Node module?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json, yarnpkg

I want to force using `yarn install` instead of `npm install`. I want to raise an error in `npm install`. What should I do in `package.json`?

Comment: What error you are facing with **npm install**

Comment: It's likely not an error that he's facing, but rather a desire to ensure his entire team is using yarn. Yarn fixes a lot of problems caused by npm when working on a team.

Comment: Here in 2022 I think this "Yarn fixes NPM" notion is outdated. NPM had a rough patch around 2015 but it seems fine to me now.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

> **UPDATE:** [Alexander's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41233367/264794) is the better solution and uses the same technique I describe here. I am leaving my answer in tact for posterity. The original point of my answer was to show that you can execute a small node script which should work on all platforms.

In your preinstall script you can run a mini node script which should work on all platforms, whereas things like `pgrep` (and other common *nix commands and operators) won't work on Windows until Windows 10 has received widespread adoption.

I tested the below script on Node v4.7.0 (npm v2.15.11) and Node v7.2.1 (npm v3.10.10). I assume it works on everything in between. It works by checking the environment variables on the currently running process - the `npm_execpath` is the path to the currently running "npm" script. In the case of yarn, it should point to `/path/to/yarn/on/your/machine/yarn.js`.

```
"scripts": {
    "preinstall": "node -e \"if(process.env.npm_execpath.indexOf('yarn') === -1) throw new Error('You must use Yarn to install, not NPM')\""
}
```

You can read more about npm scripts here: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts

As far as the `npm_execpath` environment variable, while not documented I doubt that it will ever change. It's been around for multiple major releases of `npm` and it doesn't really pass the *"there's a better name for this"* test.

Comment: && is fine in npm scripts since they are executed by command prompt, not powershell.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I thought the Windows equivalent of `&&` was `&` - I was mistaken (`&` is the windows equivalent of `;`). I have updated my answer.

Comment: The quotations matter on windows and will give an error if you use single quotes for the -e argument:
`"preinstall": "node -e \"if(process.env.npm_execpath.indexOf('yarn') === -1) throw new Error('You must use Yarn to install, not NPM')\""`

Comment: Thanks @Thomas - I have updated the code above. I had to use single quotes inside the script - can you verify that it works on Windows? Thanks!

Comment: That appears to match what we have, so should work. I have a Mac and my coworkers have Windows so we routinely break things for eachother.

Comment: Ryan's answer didn't work for me on Mac because my `npm_execpath` is `/Users/zackmorris/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js` even when running under `npm install`.  I think that [Alexander O'Mara's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41233367/539149) is more robust and [extended it with a general check for running under yarn or npm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49438180/539149).

Comment: if I try`npm install package` rather than `npm install`, which hooks I can use?

Comment: There aren't any hooks when adding individual packages to your project. If someone tries to add a new package to your project using npm, you would need to catch that during code review and instruct them to use yarn.

Comment: I disagree with you saying Alexander's answer is better.  His doesn't work on Windows and yours does.  They are effectively doing the same thing, but this one is cross platform.

Comment: Unfortunately if you add this script to a package that is later on imported by another package, then that "importing" package won't be able to use npm anymore. This is because `npm@v7` broke `preinstall` hook. Thank [them](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/2660#issuecomment-1204332652).

Comment: @jtompl - thanks for the info - this is not surprising at this point. I know the npm team works hard, and I've known a couple people on the team - they're good people, smart people. I don't know why they continue to do stuff like this though. That being said, I would highly advise against using this particular script on a distributed package because you don't want to force people to use a certain package manager - that's just rude. This is more intended for projects which have many contributors to ensure that everyone is using the expected package manager.

Answer (score 20):

Most of the answers here involve hacky scripts but there's a built-in way to achieve this which I posted over on the [Yarn GitHub issue](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/4895#issuecomment-545644733). Unlike some of the other ways, <strike>this works for any and all NPM commands</strike> -- actually a bug in `npm` means it blocks `npm install` but not `npm install <package>`. Hopefully, though, the developer's suspicions would already be raised from doing an `npm install`.

You add a fake engine version like so in package.json (you may want to tweak the yarn and node entries):

```
  "engines": {
    "npm": "please-use-yarn",
    "yarn": ">= 1.17.3",
    "node": ">= 12.5.0"
  }
```

Then you add an .npmrc file to the project root with this:

```
engine-strict = true
```

Running NPM then raises an error:

```
npm ERR! code ENOTSUP
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported engine for root@: wanted: {"npm":"please-use-yarn","yarn":">= 1.17.3","node":">= 12.5.0"} (current: {"node":"12.9.1","npm":"6.10.2"})
npm ERR! notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: root@
```

Comment: This worked best for me. The selected answer (or suggested answer in the selected answer) does prevent `npm` but also prevented `yarn` command from running. This seems cleanest, and easy to understand the error message output.

Comment: Caution!! This will interfere when publishing the package, and reinstall it somewhere else with `engine-strict=true` (because `package.json` with `engines` field is published). Rather, I recommend not using `engines` in `package.json` at all.

Comment: @Polv Consumers of the packge should not have .nmprc. This means `engine-strict` is false for them. Later versions of NPM will only throw a warning for this. I

Comment: I have `engine-strict` set to true in my ~/.npmrc and have `"npm": "no-npm-only-yarn",` in my engines property but when I install with npm I get no warnings. There's no .npmrc in the root of the project folder. Not sure what's going on but this answer isn't working for me. Node 14.18.3.

Comment: @jcollum Are you by any chance doing "npm install <package>" rather than "npm install". Sadly, a bug in NPM means it doesnt protect the former. Theres some chat about it in the github issue on the answer.

You should also check that using an `.npmrc` in your project directory works, rather than relying on the one in your home dir.

Comment: I made a separate question that clarifies what I'm doing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71681238/how-can-i-throw-an-error-if-someone-tries-to-install-a-package-in-a-repo-that-us

Answer (score 16):

Like the other answers, I'd recommend using a [`preinstall` script](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) and checking your environment. For a portable solution that won't have false-positives if another npm process happens to be running, using `node -e 'JS_CODE'` is probably the best option.

In that JS code, you can check the package manager's path using the following:

```
process.env.npm_execpath
```

Yarn's binary is `yarn.js`, compared to `npm-cli.js` used by NPM. We can use a regex like the following to check that this string ends with `yarn.js`.

```
/yarn\.js$/
```

By using this regex, we can be sure it won't accidentally match somewhere earlier in the file system. Most-likely `yarn` won't appear in the file path, but you can never be too sure.

Here's a minimal example:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "preinstall": "node -e 'if(!/yarn\\.js$/.test(process.env.npm_execpath))throw new Error(\"Use yarn\")'"
  }
}
```

Of course, the user will still be able to get around this check be editing the JSON or using the `--ignore-scripts` options:

```
npm install --ignore-scripts
```

Comment: This answer worked best for me on Mac OS.  I've extended Alexander's answer with a thorough explanation of the logic involved and a general example for detecting yarn/npm at https://stackoverflow.com/a/49438180/539149

Comment: This doesn't work on Windows, but the accepted answer does, for anyone looking in the future.

Comment: @JulianI have it working on Windows 10 by changing the regex to use just one slash: `!/yarn\.js`

Answer (score 14):

After trying these options and not being very satisfied, I recommend [only-allow](https://github.com/pnpm/only-allow#readme).

Just add:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "preinstall": "npx only-allow yarn"
  }
}
```

I like that it provides a clear warning message, and instructions how to install yarn:

[image: screenshot of only-allow error output]

Credit to [Adam Thomas'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61911013/2368141) answer for providing the thread recommending this.

Comment: What happens if the user doesn't have npm installed at all?

Comment: @Mark Please see https://github.com/pnpm/only-allow/issues/1#issuecomment-727667757

Comment: I suggest anyone who is going to use this script to use `npx only-allow@1.0.0 yarn` just to be safe.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [preinstall](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) hook along with some shell script to achieve this.

**sample package.json:**

```
  "scripts": {
    "preinstall": "pgrep npm && exit 1"
  }
```

Comment: This didn't work for me on OSX as it produced false positives. For example, running `pgrep npm` directly in Terminal returns a process ID because I happen to have a server running which was started with an npm script.

Answer (score 2):

I've just released a module that includes a CLI for this (useful for npm `preinstall` scripts): https://github.com/adjohnson916/use-yarn

Also, I've just released a helper for [Danger](http://danger.systems/js/) to check for missing `yarn.lock` changes on CI:
https://github.com/adjohnson916/danger-yarn-lock

See also discussion here:

- https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/1732
- https://github.com/alexanderwallin/use-yarn-instead/issues/1

Answer (score 2):

If you want to simply test whether packages are being installed under yarn or npm, I tweaked [Alexander O'Mara's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41112752/539149) slightly since it worked for me on OS X:

```
"scripts": {
    "preinstall": "if node -e \"process.exitCode=!/yarn\\.js$/.test(process.env.npm_execpath)\" ; then echo yarn ; else echo npm ; fi",
    "postinstall": ""
}
```

There are quite a few concepts happening in this short snippet:

- The `\\.` portion is escaped so that `\\` becomes `\` and results in a properly escaped `\.` to detect a period in the regex.
- `process.exitCode=` can be used to set the process's exit code and is safer than calling `process.exit(N)` due to the asynchronous nature of Node.js.
- In [Alexander's example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41112752/539149), `throw new Error(\"Use yarn\")` caused node to exit with code 1 and print the stack trace to `stderr`.  You can try running these on the console to see how that works: `node -e 'throw new Error("Oops")'` and `node -e 'throw new Error("Oops")' 2> /dev/null` (which directs the `stderr` stream to `/dev/null`).  Then you can verify that the exit code was 1 with `echo $?` (which prints the last exit code).
- The shell's `if XXXX ; then YYYY ; else ZZZZ ; fi` conditional logic checks the exit code of `XXXX` and goes to the `then` case for 0 (any other value goes to the `else` case).  So if the regex detects `yarn.js` at the end of `process.env.npm_execpath` then it returns true.  This must be negated so that the node process exits with code 0 and satisfies the `if`.
- You could also `console.log()` the regex result and compare the output in the shell (this is just a little more verbose).  Here are some examples of how to do that: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/52801 and https://superuser.com/a/688902
- You can append `true ;` or `false ;` to any shell statement to set the exit code manually.  For example you can try `true ; echo $?` or `false ; echo $?`.
- You can also leave off the `else echo npm ;` portion entirely if you don't need it.

With all of that out of the way, you can substitute the `echo yarn` and `echo npm` portions with other commands.  For example, you could put multiple commands in a subshell like `(echo yarn)` or `echo $(echo yarn)`.

In my case, I needed to work around an issue where one of the packages installed but had bugs under yarn so I had to run an `npm install --ignore-scripts` in the success case.  Note that this should probably never be done in production, but can be a lifesaver if you just need to get something done or don't have control over which package manager will be used down the road.

I haven't tried this on Windows, so if someone can test the syntax there I will update my answer with what works.  It would be best if the `preinstall` script is identical under both Windows and the Mac/Linux shell.

Answer (score 2):

As some answers have already showed, you can use the [only-allow](https://www.npmjs.com/package/only-allow) package like so:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "preinstall": "npx only-allow [npm|cnpm|pnpm|yarn]"
  }
}
```

However, [NodeJS v16.9.0 and v14.19.0 support a new experimental `packageManager` field in the package.json file](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#packagemanager).

> Type: `<string>`
>
> ```json
> {
>   "packageManager": "<package manager name>@<version>"
> }
> ```
>
> The `"packageManager"` field defines which package manager is expected to be used when working on the current project. It can be set to any of the [supported package managers](https://nodejs.org/api/corepack.html#supported-package-managers), and will ensure that your teams use the exact same package manager versions without having to install anything else other than Node.js.
>
> This field is currently experimental and needs to be opted-in; check the [Corepack](https://nodejs.org/api/corepack.html) page for details about the procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Found an alternate solution on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/node/comments/gphaue/is_there_anyway_to_prevent_npm_install_for_a_yarn/). I added this to the end of my `.zshenv` file:

```
NPM_PATH=$(which npm)
npm () {
  if [ -e yarn.lock ]
  then
    echo "Please use yarn with this project"
  else
    $NPM_PATH "$@"
  fi
}
```

It now stops me from absentmindedly running commands like `npm i` on any yarn project on my Mac.