# Preventing npm commands in favor of pnpm

Tags: npm, zsh, oh-my-zsh, pnpm

I would like to switch to using PNPM over NPM for the usual reasons. Unfortunately cut and paste, or muscle memory takes over sometimes and I will accidentally use NPM to install a package in a project that is using already using PNPM. Things do not go well for that project anymore.

I am hoping to block or alias NPM commands in favor of PNMP.

Things I have tried:

1. [Only Allow](https://pnpm.io/only-allow-pnpm) - although promoted on the PNPM site, it does not seem to work, at least not work for individual imports which is the most common use case.
2. Since my terminal is [Oh My ZSH](https://ohmyz.sh/), I found [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41076172/force-yarn-install-instead-of-npm-install-for-node-module/#comment112890527_62176124) to add to ~/.zshrc to block npm if in a directory containing a PNPM lockfile.

```bash
NPM_PATH=$(which npm)
npm () {
  if [ -e PNPM-lock.yaml ]
  then
    echo "Please use PNPM with this project"
  elif [ -e yarn.lock ]
  then
    echo "Please use Yarn with this project"
  else
    $NPM_PATH "$@"
  fi
}
```

This seems to work for my purposes, but does anyone have any cleaner / less zsh-specific alternatives?

And in the case where it does happen, what is the recommended steps to recover a PNMP projected tainted by an NPM install?

Comment: That's what I use as well.  It could be a package-deal thing   I tried `pnpm env` and it has `npm` bundled.

`$ pwd && ls` produces 
`/home/michael/.local/share/pnpm` and
`global  node  nodejs  npm  npx  pnpm  `pnpx  store
```

Answer (score 5):

You've already mentioned the [only-allow](https://www.npmjs.com/package/only-allow) package.

[NodeJS v16.9.0 and v14.19.0 support a new experimental `packageManager` field in the package.json file](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#packagemanager).

> Type: `<string>`
>
> ```json
> {
>   "packageManager": "<package manager name>@<version>"
> }
> ```
>
> The `"packageManager"` field defines which package manager is expected to be used when working on the current project. It can be set to any of the [supported package managers](https://nodejs.org/api/corepack.html#supported-package-managers), and will ensure that your teams use the exact same package manager versions without having to install anything else other than Node.js.
>
> This field is currently experimental and needs to be opted-in; check the [Corepack](https://nodejs.org/api/corepack.html) page for details about the procedure.

To recover a PNMP projected tainted by an NPM install, as long as you've specified your dependency versions as you'd really like them to work, you could just delete the `node_modules` folder and the [package-lock.json file](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-lock-json). But you could also take a look at [PNPM's `import` subcommand](https://pnpm.io/cli/import)

> `pnpm import` generates a `pnpm-lock.yaml` from another package manager's lockfile [...]

Answer (score 4):

When it's project-specific you could use this https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-force-use-yarn-or-npm/

I've been using it because we switched to PNPM, and I was still constantly using yarn for some reason.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32996335)

Answer (score 1):

I have added the following function called npm in my `.zshrc` file

```
npm () {
    bash -c "if grep -sq 'pnpm' package.json; then pnpm $@; else npm $@; fi"
}
```

This function tests if you have mentioned `pnpm` as your "packageManager" in which case it uses pnpm, otherwise defaults to npm

Answer (score 1):

1. 

According to [these](https://dev.to/andreychernykh/yarn-npm-to-pnpm-migration-guide-2n04) [articles](https://britishgeologicalsurvey.github.io/development/migrating-from-npm-to-pnpm/) it is enough to add to your package.json:

```
"scripts": {
  "preinstall": "npx only-allow pnpm", 
  ...
}
```

I assume that you first need to install the `only-allow` package for that, even though such a step is missing from both tutorials.

2.

Alternatively, [this article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-force-use-yarn-or-npm/) was written for Yarn, but should apply to pnpm equally:
You can create/edit a .npmrc file with the following

```
engine-strict = true
```

And then in package.json

```
"engines": {
   "npm": "please-use-pnpm",
   "pnpm": ">= 2.0.0"
},
```

3. 

Finally, it should be pointed out that Node v16+ supports a expected package manager with the experimental Corepack

```
corepack prepare pnpm@latest --activate
```

I have not tested any of the above, but they should all prevent running `npm` instead of `pnpm`.

Answer (score 0):

edit package.json file, add this:

```
"engines": {
    "npm": "please-use-pnpm",
    "yarn": "please-use-pnpm",
    "pnpm": ">= 8.0.0"
},
```

create .npmrc

```
engine-strict = true
```